# Unauthorized request to start container. This token is expired

Tags: hadoop, containers, hadoop-yarn

I am getting  "Unauthorized request to start container.  This token is expired."
How to resovle it. The problem is reported on different forums, but I could not find an solution to it.

Below is the execution log

```
15/02/26 16:41:02 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1424968835929_0001
15/02/26 16:41:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://101-master15:8088/proxy/application_1424968835929_0001/
15/02/26 16:41:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1424968835929_0001
15/02/26 16:41:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1424968835929_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/02/26 16:41:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/02/26 16:41:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1424968835929_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1424968835929_0001 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1424968835929_0001_000002. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container. 
This token is expired. current time is 1424969604829 found 1424969463686
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.launch(AMLauncher.java:122)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.run(AMLauncher.java:249)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
. Failing the application.
15/02/26 16:41:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
Time taken: 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 9 seconds.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257878/yarnexception-unauthorized-request-to-start-container)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257878/yarnexception-unauthorized-request-to-start-container this could help you.

Answer (score 2):

This exception occurs when your nodes have different time settings. Make sure that your all 3 nodes have same time n timezone settings and then restart computer.

This worked for me . Hope this help to you as well !!!!