# Spark 2.1 + Yarn application has already ended

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-2.0

we are using spark application version 2.1 in out ambari cluster

ambari thrift servers isn't stable and restarted all times

from the log we can see that:

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
```

we found the following link that described solution for this problem

https://markobigdata.com/2016/08/11/yarn-application-has-already-ended-it-might-have-been-killed-or-unable-to-launch-application-master/

but after we set the parameters as described in the article , the problem still  exsist

please advice what is the solution for this?

full log:

```
tail -f  spark-hive-org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2-1-master01.sys873dns.com.out
Spark Command: /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Dhdp.version=2.6.0.3-8 -cp /usr/hdp/current/spark2-thriftserver/conf/:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-thriftserver/jars/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/ -Xmx10000m org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --conf spark.driver.memory=50g --properties-file /usr/hdp/current/spark2-thriftserver/conf/spark-thrift-sparkconf.conf --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 --name Thrift JDBC/ODBC Server --executor-cores 7 spark-internal
========================================
Warning: Master yarn-client is deprecated since 2.0. Please use master "yarn" with specified deploy mode instead.
18/02/08 09:38:07 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2320)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLEnv$.init(SparkSQLEnv.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:745)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
18/02/08 09:38:07 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
18/02/08 09:38:07 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I give also the yarn logs:

```
   grep -i erro yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-master01.sys873dns.com.log

018-02-08 11:19:00,993 INFO  zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:logStartConnect(1019)) - Opening socket connection to server master01.sys873dns.com/23.1.29.61:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2018-02-08 11:19:15,767 ERROR resourcemanager.ResourceManager (LogAdapter.java:error(69)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2018-02-08 11:19:27,281 INFO  zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:logStartConnect(1019)) - Opening socket connection to server master01.sys873dns.com/23.1.29.61:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2018-02-08 11:29:00,064 INFO  zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:logStartConnect(1019)) - Opening socket connection to server master01.sys873dns.com/23.1.29.61:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2018-02-08 11:29:01,839 INFO  zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:logStartConnect(1019)) - Opening socket connection to server master01.sys873dns.com/23.1.29.61:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2018-02-08 11:29:15,725 ERROR resourcemanager.ResourceManager (LogAdapter.java:error(69)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2018-02-08 11:29:27,033 INFO  zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:logStartConnect(1019)) - Opening socket connection to server master03.sys873dns.com/23.1.29.63:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)



ons.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
2018-02-08 12:56:11,144 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(273)) - Error launching appattempt_1518089370033_0028_000008. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
2018-02-08 12:59:39,822 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(273)) - Error launching appattempt_1518089370033_0029_000002. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
2018-02-08 13:00:01,671 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(273)) - Error launching appattempt_1518089370033_0029_000004. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
2018-02-08 13:00:18,062 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(273)) - Error launching appattempt_1518089370033_0029_000006. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
2018-02-08 13:00:20,245 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(273)) - Error launching appattempt_1518089370033_0030_000003. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
2018-02-08 13:00:42,100 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(273)) - Error launching appattempt_1518089370033_0030_000006. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
2018-02-08 13:00:56,310 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(273)) - Error launching appattempt_1518089370033_0030_000008. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
2018-02-08 13:00:58,511 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(273)) - Error launching appattempt_1518089370033_0030_000010. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
2018-02-08 13:00:58,537 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:transition(1063)) - Application application_1518089370033_0030 failed 10 times due to Error launching appattempt_1518089370033_0030_000010. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Unauthorized request to start container.
```

last log

```
2018-02-08 14:14:54,410 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:handle(778)) - application_1518089370033_0050 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
2018-02-08 14:14:54,410 INFO  capacity.ParentQueue (ParentQueue.java:removeApplication(385)) - Application removed - appId: application_1518089370033_0050 user: hive leaf-queue of parent: root #applications: 1
2018-02-08 14:14:54,412 INFO  integration.RMRegistryOperationsService (RMRegistryOperationsService.java:onApplicationCompleted(119)) - Application application_1518089370033_0050 completed, purging application-level records
2018-02-08 14:14:54,412 INFO  integration.RMRegistryOperationsService (RMRegistryOperationsService.java:purgeRecordsAsync(198)) -  records under / with ID application_1518089370033_0050 and policy application: {}
2018-02-08 14:14:55,393 INFO  rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl (RMContainerImpl.java:handle(422)) - container_e09_1518089370033_0049_10_000001 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to COMPLETED
2018-02-08 14:14:55,393 INFO  scheduler.SchedulerNode (SchedulerNode.java:releaseContainer(220)) - Released container container_e09_1518089370033_0049_10_000001 of capacity <memory:10240, vCores:1> on host worker02.sys768.com:45454, which currently has 0 containers, <memory:0, vCores:0> used and <memory:30720, vCores:6> available, release resources=true
2018-02-08 14:14:55,393 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:rememberTargetTransitionsAndStoreState(1209)) - Updating application attempt appattempt_1518089370033_0049_000010 with final state: FAILED, and exit status: -1000
2018-02-08 14:14:55,398 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(809)) - appattempt_1518089370033_0049_000010 State change from LAUNCHED to FINAL_SAVING
2018-02-08 14:14:55,399 INFO  integration.RMRegistryOperationsService (RMRegistryOperationsService.java:onContainerFinished(144)) - Container container_e09_1518089370033_0049_10_000001 finished, purging container-level records
2018-02-08 14:14:55,400 INFO  integration.RMRegistryOperationsService (RMRegistryOperationsService.java:purgeRecordsAsync(198)) -  records under / with ID container_e09_1518089370033_0049_10_000001 and policy container: {}
2018-02-08 14:14:55,408 INFO  resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService (ApplicationMasterService.java:unregisterAttempt(685)) - Unregistering app attempt : appattempt_1518089370033_0049_000010
2018-02-08 14:14:55,408 INFO  security.AMRMTokenSecretManager (AMRMTokenSecretManager.java:applicationMasterFinished(124)) - Application finished, removing password for appattempt_1518089370033_0049_000010
2018-02-08 14:14:55,408 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(809)) - appattempt_1518089370033_0049_000010 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
2018-02-08 14:14:55,408 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:transition(1330)) - The number of failed attempts is 10. The max attempts is 10
2018-02-08 14:14:55,409 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:rememberTargetTransitionsAndStoreState(1123)) - Updating application application_1518089370033_0049 with final state: FAILED
2018-02-08 14:14:55,409 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:handle(778)) - application_1518089370033_0049 State change from ACCEPTED to FINAL_SAVING
2018-02-08 14:14:55,409 INFO  recovery.RMStateStore (RMStateStore.java:transition(228)) - Updating info for app: application_1518089370033_0049
2018-02-08 14:14:55,409 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:doneApplicationAttempt(811)) - Application Attempt appattempt_1518089370033_0049_000010 is done. finalState=FAILED
2018-02-08 14:14:55,409 INFO  scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo (AppSchedulingInfo.java:clearRequests(124)) - Application application_1518089370033_0049 requests cleared
2018-02-08 14:14:55,410 INFO  capacity.LeafQueue (LeafQueue.java:removeApplicationAttempt(795)) - Application removed - appId: application_1518089370033_0049 user: hive queue: default #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 0 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 0
2018-02-08 14:14:55,417 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:transition(1063)) - Application application_1518089370033_0049 failed 10 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1518089370033_0049_000010 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://master02.sys768.com:8088/cluster/app/application_1518089370033_0049 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-1212891131-25.1.53.61-1518077044052:blk_1073741833_1009 file=/hdp/apps/2.6.0.3-8/spark2/spark2-hdp-yarn-archive.tar.gz
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
2018-02-08 14:14:55,418 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:handle(778)) - application_1518089370033_0049 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
2018-02-08 14:14:55,418 INFO  capacity.ParentQueue (ParentQueue.java:removeApplication(385)) - Application removed - appId: application_1518089370033_0049 user: hive leaf-queue of parent: root #applications: 0
2018-02-08 14:14:55,419 INFO  integration.RMRegistryOperationsService (RMRegistryOperationsService.java:onApplicationCompleted(119)) - Application application_1518089370033_0049 completed, purging application-level records
2018-02-08 14:14:55,419 INFO  integration.RMRegistryOperationsService (RMRegistryOperationsService.java:purgeRecordsAsync(198)) -  records under / with ID application_1518089370033_0049 and policy application: {}
[root@master02 yarn]#
```

Comment: This is the vague exception stacktrace that is shown in the driver because the driver cant really get any more information. You need to check your yarn logs for the application and see what the error is.

Comment: I access to the folder - cd /var/log/hadoop/yarn , but no logs under this folder , is it true what I am doing?

Comment: I am not sure where exactly the log files would be, but you can check this from the resource manager UI page too. You can access this by going into ambari->yarn->quick links->node->resource manager UI.

Here you can check for all the applications that have run and all of their logs too. If you dont find logs with proper information here, you probably need to increase logging level in YARN.

Comment: see my update - "I give also the yarn logs:" , can you please tell me if the errors as described are gives us something ?

Comment: Typically the error is somewhere in the next line or so and that's still missing. Maybe just look at the total applications log instead of grep for error. For example, look at the error message on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257878/yarnexception-unauthorized-request-to-start-container

Comment: I attached the "last log" from yarn , I think more details there but I not see the root cause there , do you see something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164759/discussion-between-enodmilvado-and-subramaniam-ramasubramanian).

Comment: I used to get this error when I used to prematurely close the sparkContext. See if you are doing that in the code.